# Variable number of arguments in PL/SQL stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, arguments

Can a procedure PL/SQL take a variable number of arguments?

In my case, the procedure is called by the submit button of a form, and the form has variable number of inputs.

Comment: imo use either default values or create several overloads calling a base procedure.  Put all of your common processing in the base proc that is called by all other overloaded procs.  The overloaded procs will each have additional processing particular to that call of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't mention it, but are you using mod_plsql?

If so, you should read about [flexible parameter passing](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14010/concept.htm#i1005764).

In short, prefix your procedure name with an exclamation mark in your browser and define your procedure with a name_array and value_array.

Comment: I searched for flexible parameter passing like you said, and i found this : http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:19276873018565

Problem solved ! Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks for accepting. The text in my answer is also a link and it would have saved you from searching again yourself :-)

Answer (score 4):

Sort of. You can give the procedure parameter default values:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc( p_value_a NUMBER DEFAULT 1, 
                         p_value_b NUMBER DEFAULT 2 ) AS
    ...
```

which you could call like this:

```
myproc( 999 );
```

or like this:

```
myproc (p_value_b => 11 );
```

Comment: I'd rather use NULL as the default value. But otherwise, the answer is good.

Comment: I thought about default values, but the number of arguments can be very big.
A procedure with 100 arguments with a null default value, strange no ?

Comment: I've never seen a procedure that needs 100 arguments. If you have 100 form variables, you need to do some server-side processing before sending it to your database.