# Arbitrary number of parameters plsql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, parameters, varchar

I am wondering whether it is possible to pass arbitrary number of VARCHAR parameters into PLSQL procedure/function. So far I have this

```
DECLARE   
--TYPE thisType IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);
    var TypePack.thisType;
BEGIN
    var:=TypePack.thisType('a','b','c');
    L10B(TypePack.thisType('a','b'));
    /****** OR ******/
    L10B(var);
END;
```

L10B is SP which works with given parameter. What do I want to achieve is something like

```
L10B('string1','string2','string3',...,'stringX');
```

where X is not known in advance. Enter as many arguments as I want then take entered text (e.g. 'string2','string3') and before it is "given" to procedure convert it to that type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179285/variable-number-of-arguments-in-pl-sql-stored-procedure)

Comment: @furman87 Thank you, but this is not exactly what do I look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PLSQL compiler does not support arbitrary numbers of parameters. You can pass a VARRAY or associative array (index-by-table) into a function, giving you the option to pass lists of VARCHAR2.