# How to call Oracle stored procedure using muliple param values from table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have requirement to call stored procedure for which input parameters are multiples values are coming from table.

For example:

```
sp(p1,p2,p2,...);
```

Table looks like this:

```
Col1 | Col2
-----+-------
p1   | val1
p2   | Val2
p3   | val3
```

How we can achieve this in PL/SQL block?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable number of arguments in PL/SQL stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179285/variable-number-of-arguments-in-pl-sql-stored-procedure)

Comment: You select the values from the table into variables, then pass those variables to the procedure.

Comment: @DaveCosta OP's question is that the number of variables itself varies and not fixed as new rows could be added to the table.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar- Yes I have to map store procedures parameter with col1 & assign col2 respective values to variable in order to call sp.

Comment: @NileshKadam See the link I provided above, it already has an answer.

Comment: @ Lalit Kuamr - Thank for link. do you have an sample code how to use name array & value array to achieve this it would be grateful !!